# Enêsima iteração de um loop aninhado

Tags: python, iterator, generators

Como utilizar geradores/iteradores para obter a ênesima iteração de um loop aninhado? Eu tenho a seguinte função implementada de uma maneira extremamente ineficiente.

```
from pprint import pprint

def center(i, j):
    s = 50
    for k, v1 in enumerate(range(int(s / 2), s * 8, s)):
        for n, v2 in enumerate(range(int(s / 2), s * 8, s)):
            if (i, j) == (k, n):
                return (v1, v2)

pprint(center(0,0))  # -> (25, 25)
pprint(center(6,3))  # -> (325, 175)
```

Eu tentei implementar um gerador para obter somente o c(x, y) mas não sei como fazê-lo.

```
def centerGenerator():
    s = 50
    for k in range(int(s / 2), s * 8, s):
        for n in range(int(s / 2), s * 8, s):
            yield k, n

def center(i, j):
    for c in centerGenerator():
        pass # como obter c(i, j) do gerador?

pprint(center(0,0))  # -> (25, 25)
pprint(center(6,3))  # -> (325, 175)
```

Gostaria de obter somente a iteração desejada sem ter que gerar do começo até o ponto necessário. Como se fosse uma função matemática, mas obviamente, usando geradores/iteradores para ser mais eficiente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Gostaria de obter somente a iteração desejada sem ter que gerar do
>   começo até o ponto necessário

Se você precisa disso, então não precisa de laço, nem de geradores, nem nada - apenas uma transformação de coordenadas para o seu sistema de coordeandas - que, dada uma escala `s` é basicamente somar um offset de s / 2, e aumenta de s em s:

```
def center(i, j, s=50):
   return s // 2 + i * s, s // 2 + j * s
```

E, a não ser que o gerador dependa ou de um efeito colateral feito a cada passo (por exemplo, ler uma ou mais linhas de um arquivo), ou de um efeito acumulado em cada passo (por exemplo, vai percorrendo um vetor e somando os valores acumulados), você sempre vai poder ir direto no ponto desejado, só fazendo as contas.

Para os casos em que os passos anteriores são necessários, então os passos são necessários - a função `itertools.islice` pode prover uma forma mais curta de percorrer todos os pontos necessários de um gerador antes do ponto desejado - mas não faz isso de forma mais fácil de entender pr quem estiver olhando.

Por exemplo, para o gerador:

```
def acumulador(n):
    valor = 0
    for i in range(0, n):
        valor += i
        yield valor
```

Se eu quiser imprimir apenas os valores entre 6 e 8 da iteração posso fazer:

```
from itertools import islice

for i in islice(acumulador(10), 6, 8):
    print(i)
```

Mas note que o `islice` não tem como "adivinhar" o que o iterador faz em cada passo - a única coisa que ele faz é selecionar os valores pedidos na chamada, mas internamente todos os valores do acumulador são usados, até se chegar na sétima interação (que tem índice 6) - aí, em vez de descartar o valor, ele faz `yield` dele, e o valor é usado no `for` externo.

**Reiterando então**: poder ir direto para um valor do laço  não tem a ver com possibilidades da linguagem de programação, e sim, com a simples lógica: ou o valor Depende dos resultados anteriores pra ser calculado, e se depende, você tem que passar por todas as interações, não tem o que fazer (a linguagem até tem o islice justamente para "esconder" as interações que não são necessárias), ou, como no exemplo da pergunta, o valor é independente dos cálculos dos valores anteriores na interação, e só depende das variáveis numéricas: nesse caso, é só fazer justamente isso, a conta direto, sem nenhum laço.

Comment: Entendi. A solução matemática é sempre mais eficiente. Então, só para por um ponto final nisso, no caso que tenho dois loops aninhados usar o islice para obter os valores de exemplo (center(0,0) e center(6,3)) ficaria como? No caso como ficariam os argumentos para a chamada.

Comment: O "islice" não seria apropriado nesse caso (veja que sua função center não faz nada, o islice seria direto para o `centerGenerator` - mas você quer achar uma solução que depende de dois parâmetros, e  o `islice` simplesmente chama o gerador sequencialmente, até chegar na posição desejada.

Comment: Então, se fosse pra insistir em fazer isso, podemos, sabendo que nesse caso específico, a largura de cada linha é "8" - então transformamos o i e j na posição linear antes de chamar o islice, e usamos o chamada `next` para recuperar o primeiro valor liberado pelo islice:  `next(islice(centerGenerator(), i * 8 + j, i * 8 + j + 1))`

Comment: Na verdade, esse aí parece mais o caso de uso pra uma _classe_ do que para geradores - você cria uma classe, que tem como parâmetros a escala e possivelmente o tamanho do seu grid (no caso 8 x 8), e põe métodos e propriedades para converter as coordenadas em pixels (suponho) para as coordenadas internas, e iterar todas as coordenadas de pixels se for o caso.

Comment: Certo. O interesse maior é saber se é possível obter somente e simplesmente o enésimo valor da iteração de um loop ou loop aninhado. Sem ter que gerar todos os valores até aquela iteração. Acho que li em algum lugar sobre geradores e iteradores e fiquei com essa possibilidade na mente. Eu só peguei um cotexto de um script antigo de damas para tentar implementar isso.

Comment: (Passei essa resposta ao comentário  para o último parágrafo na resposta mesmo)